# Raspberry Pi Uwp App With Angular

Tags: windows-iot

Fairly new to all things pi so bare with me.

I would like to use Windows 10 IoT , UWP app and program in Angular 6. 
I know it is possible to set the start page of a Javascript UWP app to be that of a locally running angular app ie pointing the uwp app to start at `localhost:4200`.

My question is this , will angular still be able to access the GPIO pins with the relevant NPM packages? The UWP app will simply serve as a view into the locally running angular app but im worried that I cannot access the GPIO pins .

The reason I am taking this approach is because I am already familiar with this framework and would prefer to use it rather than using Xaml or the default javascript uwp project.

Any starting points and links would be appreciated guys!